# Python Class DRY

Tags: python, class

I wrote the following python class. Now I repeat `if settings.MIXPANEL_ID:`in every function and I wonder if there is a better way to write this Class?

```
class MixpanelClass:
    def __init__(self):
        if settings.MIXPANEL_ID:
            mp = Mixpanel(settings.MIXPANEL_ID)

    def mp_track_event(user_id, event, property=None):
        if settings.MIXPANEL_ID:
            mp.track(user_id, event, property)

    def mp_people_set(user_id, property):
        if settings.MIXPANEL_ID:
            mp.people_set(user_id, property)

    def mp_people_increment(user_id, property):
        if settings.MIXPANEL_ID:
            mp.people_increment(user_id, property)

    def mp_people_track_charge(user_id, revenue, property):
        if settings.MIXPANEL_ID:
            mp.people_track_charge(user_id, revenue, property)

    def mp_get_distinct_id(request):
        if settings.MIXPANEL_ID:
            mp_cookie_name = 'mp_' + settings.MIXPANEL_ID + '_mixpanel'
            mp_cookie = request.COOKIES.get(mp_cookie_name, None)
            if mp_cookie:
                unquoted = unquote(mp_cookie)
                dictionary = literal_eval(unquoted)
                return dictionary.get('distinct_id')
```

Comment: What is this class for? Why are all its methods static?

Comment: I thought that way I don't have to pass `mp = Mixpanel(settings.MIXPANEL_ID)` everytime, but can just do it once in my Class. I am calling these function in different views of my Django project.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to answer your question - maybe `if settings.MIXPANEL_ID` should be checked before calling a method, and the method called only if the state allows it?

Comment: You may get better feedback by putting a more complete program on [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: `mp` should be an instance attribute (`self.mp`), not a local variable, but what is the point of the class if `self.mp` isn't set?

Comment: The settings seem to be a MANDATORY value. Maybe you should check it in the init because I don't see any code NOT using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna make a suggestion, however, I think this still requires more info from the original poster.

---

### Solution 1: check in generic method

You could implement a generic function where you the method you want to call. You'll have to pass the function/method as an argument into that function

e.g.

```
def act_if_MIXPANEL_ID(self, method, *args, **kwargs):
    """Calls the method METHOD with the given args and kwargs"""
    if settings.MIXPANEL_ID:
        method(*args, **kwargs)
```

you can then call this method using this code:

```
class MixpanelClass(object):

    # here goes the rest of your code

    def mp_track_event(self, user_id, event, property=None):
        self.act_if_MIXPANEL_ID(self.mp.track, user_id, event, property)


    def act_if_MIXPANEL_ID(self, method, *args, **kwargs):
        """Calls the method METHOD with the given args and kwargs"""
        if settings.MIXPANEL_ID:
            method(*args, **kwargs)
```

PS: I took the liberty to make transform the statics into standard methods.

---

### Solution 2: decorators

Alternatively, you could define a decorator and annotate your methods with it. Before any call to the method, the decorator is going to be called.
It will call do the check (and in this example print something otherwise)

See here for a quick intro of decorators: [Intro](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/)

```
# This is the decorator
def check_settings(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if settings.MIXPANEL_ID:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print("Check for settings.MIXPANEL_ID failed.")
    return wrapper

class MixpanelClass:
    def __init__(self):
        if settings.MIXPANEL_ID:
            mp = Mixpanel(settings.MIXPANEL_ID)

    @check_settings
    def mp_track_event(user_id, event, property=None):
        mp.track(user_id, event, property)

    @check_settings
    def mp_people_set(user_id, property):
        mp.people_set(user_id, property)

    @check_settings
    def mp_people_increment(user_id, property):
        mp.people_increment(user_id, property)
```

Comment: I like the decorator approach, that answered my question, thank you!

Comment: @Jon-Programmer if your question is answered, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class decorator (which can decorate individual methods if so desired):

```
class enable_if:
    def __init__(self, condition):
        self.condition = condition

    def __call__(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, type):
            return self.decorate_class(obj)
        return self.decorate_callable(obj)

    def decorate_class(self, cls):
        for name in dir(cls):
            attr = getattr(cls, name)
            if callable(attr) and (name == '__init__' or not name.startswith('__') and not name.endswith('__')):
                setattr(cls, name, self.decorate_callable(attr))
        return cls

    def decorate_callable(self, func):
        def wrapper(obj, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.condition:
                return func(obj, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
```

so that with:

```
@enable_if(settings.MIXPANEL_ID)
class MixpanelClass:
    def __init__(self):
        mp = Mixpanel(settings.MIXPANEL_ID)

    def mp_track_event(user_id, event, property=None):
        mp.track(user_id, event, property)

    def mp_people_set(user_id, property):
        mp.people_set(user_id, property)

    def mp_people_increment(user_id, property):
        mp.people_increment(user_id, property)

    def mp_people_track_charge(user_id, revenue, property):
        mp.people_track_charge(user_id, revenue, property)

    def mp_get_distinct_id(request):
        mp_cookie_name = 'mp_' + settings.MIXPANEL_ID + '_mixpanel'
        mp_cookie = request.COOKIES.get(mp_cookie_name, None)
        if mp_cookie:
            unquoted = unquote(mp_cookie)
            dictionary = literal_eval(unquoted)
            return dictionary.get('distinct_id')
```

every user method and the `__init__` method of the `MixpanelClass` class would be disabled if `settings.MIXPANEL_ID` is `False`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Using decorators is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

If `settings.MIXPANEL_ID` isn't set, there doesn't seem to be any point to having an instance of `MixpanelClass`. That suggests a class definition like

```
class MixpanelClass:
    def __init__(self, mp_id):
        self.mp_id = mp_id
        self.mp = Mixpanel(mp_id)

    def mp_track_event(self, user_id, event, property=None):
        self.mp.track(user_id, event, property)

    def mp_people_set(self, user_id, property):
        self.mp.people_set(user_id, property)

    def mp_people_increment(self, user_id, property):
        self.mp.people_increment(user_id, property)

    def mp_people_track_charge(self, user_id, revenue, property):
        self.mp.people_track_charge(user_id, revenue, property)

    def mp_get_distinct_id(self, request):
        mp_cookie_name = 'mp_' + self.mp_id + '_mixpanel'
        mp_cookie = request.COOKIES.get(mp_cookie_name, None)
        if mp_cookie:
            unquoted = unquote(mp_cookie)
            dictionary = literal_eval(unquoted)
            return dictionary.get('distinct_id')
```

Now, you only instantiate `MixpanelClass` if you actually *have* an id:

```
if settings.MIXPANEL_ID:
    m = MixpanelClass(settings.MIXPANEL_ID)
```